# tensorflow datasets train mean calculation

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

How to compute the mean over the train dataset from a tensorflow dataset object? For example, from this example https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview how would you compute the mean over mnist_train efficiently?